# How to start: Embed Microsoft bot framework functionality inside an app with drag and drop config capability?

Tags: botframework, multi-tenant, direct-line-botframework, bot-framework-composer

I want to embed chatbot building functionality inside my product and use **msbotframework** As the back end. Can I achieve that? Each of my customers will have his bot, and I want to build my drag and drop interface to achieve that purpose.

The challenges I am facing are:

- when the customer creates the bot, how will it be automatically provisioned to Azure? Knowing that the drag and drop interface will create the bot, so I need to generate the code and then provision it to Azure.
- I need to have the shared backend between clients (database,
  server...etc), so I am not sure how to achieve this multitenancy.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Bot Framework Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer). It is pretty new, so if you come across bugs or suggestions/enhancements, please log those as issues in the GitHub repo.

If you don't want to use Composer (or fork and change it), then you could build your own. Composer is built on [Adaptive dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-adaptive-dialog-introduction?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), which are declarative. So you could build your own type of composer that would then build declarative dialogs that could then be used in a bot.

Comment: Thanks, Dana, what about multitenancy, do you have any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: I guess it depends on the specifics. I think that's too abstract of a question at this point. If you can give more examples, that might help. In theory, you can use Composer to (have users) create the dialogs, then additional code that would be in place to implement your shared backend.